# Performance of insert statement with CTE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 external tables, lets call them A and B. I also have an internal table C. A and B have some overlapping values. I want to write a procedure that writes all values from A to C and then all values from B that I don't already (from A) to C. So first write A to C, then write all the remaining data that was not already written from B to C.
Basically this:

```
Write A -> C 
Write B where not already written by A -> C
```

My first attempt looked like this

```
insert into C (select * from A);
insert into C (select * from B where b.id not in (select a.id from a));
```

My tables are pretty big and the datalinks slow, so this won't do because it takes to long. I assume the problem is that it has to do the `(select a.id from a)` for every entry of B. So I thought surely using CTE will help:

```
insert into C (select * from A);
insert into C 
  with A_values as (select a.id from a)
  select * from b where b.id not in a.values;
```

However, this still won't terminate (taking too long). Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: And what does "not in A -> C" mean?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: A and B have overlapping data. I want to write the data from B that was not already written from A. I will try to explain it more clearly in the question

Comment: I think you're looking for [the opposite of INTERSECT](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=opposite-of-intersect-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are describing two inserts:

```
insert into c ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from a;

insert into c ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from b
    where not exists (select 1 from c where b.id = c.id);
```

For performance, you want an index on `c(id)` -- or whatever columns are used for the comparison.